# Share intent location

Tags: android, android-intent, location

I've been trying to send a location via share intent through whatsapp, my code so far:

```
String uri = "geo:" + currentLoc.getLatitude() + "," +currentLoc.getLongitude() + "?q=" + currentLoc.getLatitude() + "," + currentLoc.getLongitude();
            Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(i);
```

The problem is that when the app chooser opens it only shows "google maps" and "waze". How do I can modify it so I can send it by many other apps that support location like whatsapp or facebook?

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50309428/2835520) works for you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW` by `Intent.ACTION_SEND` or `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`.

You can find the full information about [sending](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) and [receiving](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive) data between apps [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/).

Finally, you need to open the `Intent` like this:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share via"));
```

instead of: `startActivity(shareIntent);` as explained [here](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#send-text-content). This will create an dialog for user to choose which application wants to use for sharing.

---

**EXAMPLE CODE:**

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=" + location.latitude + "," + location.longitude;

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share in..."));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code below, this is an example from official documentation.

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my location to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.share, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.share_item);
    actionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();

    // Create the share Intent
    String shareText = URL_TO_SHARE;
    Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
        .setType("text/plain").setText(shareText).getIntent();
    actionProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    return true;
}
```

Another option you can directly specify app to open your intent by adding package name to your intent.

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Please, for more info check docs [whatsapp](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) and [android](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).